# Working with norms

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I was hoping to get some help with being able to properly work with norms and derivatives so I can actually understand my PDE course. We are currently working on Sobolev spaces.

Example, I want to show that:

$$-\int_{U} u \Delta u dx \leq C \int_{U}|u||D^2u|dx$$

$u \in C_{c}^{\infty}(U)$ with $U$ bounded.

I get to:

$$-\int_{U} u \Delta u dx \leq \int_{U} |u||\Delta u|dx$$

I know it is not very far at all, but I am so confused. I am missing some key skills in multivariable calculus.

My main question: What is $|D^2u|$? I thought that $D^2u$ was the hessian, and I'm confused about taking the norm.

If you have any links that would help me better understand operations with norms and $D^ku$ I would greatly appreciate it.

I'm really trying, but its just not clicking. Its really frustrating to be undone by the simpler concepts in an extremely theoretical PDE course.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a book using notation similar to Evans. If you are, check Appendix A, in the section *Notation for derivatives,* where we see
$$
|D^k u| = \left(\sum_{|\alpha|=k} |D^\alpha u|^2\right)^{1/2}.
$$
With this it should be pretty clear why $|\Delta u| \leq C|D^2 u|$.

Notation for derivatives is a bit weird across books. When in doubt, check your appendix or symbol glossary.

Comment: Unfortunately I have looked in the Appendix of Evans. I am still extremely confused.

I do not understand in the least how to show this and it is not clear at all to me. I'm starting to worry about having taken this course

Comment: It's nothing complicated, just the triangle inequality and the fact that $(a+b)^2 \leq a^2 + b^2$. Apply this to $|\Delta u|^2$, using the definition of $\Delta$.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not getting this, I hope I will.

I don't understand what $|\Delta u|^2$ is.

I know the definition of $\Delta u = \sum_{i=1}^n u_{x_{i}x_{i}}$ but I don't understand how to take its norm into all this.

I'm missing very key and simple knowledge on this stuff unfortunately

Comment: $|\Delta u|$ is the absolute value of $\Delta u$. Both are real-valued functions, so the absolute value should make sense.

Comment: So would it be something so simple as:

$|\Delta u|^2=|\Delta u||\Delta u|=(\sum_{i=1}^n u_{x_{i}x_{i}})^2 \leq |D^2 u|^2$

The last inequality because each of those $u_{x_{i}x_{i}}$ are included in $D^2 u$?

Then since $|\Delta u|^2 \leq |D^2 u|^2$ we must have:

$|\Delta u| \leq C |D^2 u|$.

Comment: Almost, but your second equality is actually an inequality.

Comment: But shouldn't it be:

$|\Delta u||\Delta u|=|\Delta u \Delta u|=|(\Delta u)^2|=(\Delta u)^2$

(And thank you for all your help, I`ve been needing someone to be patient with me for a long time.)

Comment: Yes, but $(\Delta u)^2 = (\sum u_{x_ix_i})^2 \leq \sum u_{x_ix_i}^2$.

Comment: And I understand.

I`m going to start working from both sides of things and break things down as low as they get so I really understand.

Thanks a lot, I`m sure you just cleared up a bunch of cobwebs for me!